# How to password protect users on Android?

Tags: multi-user

at home we share a tablet using the multi user feature of Android, which is good enough.
That said, switching users has no password protection whatsoever, so other users could log in my user and see all my mail etc...

Is there a way to protect users with passwords just like on Mac or Windows machine?

Comment: Have you tried to set-up a lock-screen password or PIN for each account?

Comment: Could you mention the device model and Android version?